# Navigations properties are not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

For some reason my edit action are not updating my navigations properties
Check de codes

```
 public ActionResult Edit(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cliente = Mapper.Map<Clientes>(clienteViewModel);
            _context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(clienteViewModel);
    }
```

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT
I added a hidden field with endereco.id on edit view and now Endereco.Id is going to controller, but the error still the same

[image]

Comment: All data are coming fine, but  the save changes do nothing.

Comment: you didn't call `_context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz he uses a UoW pattern so I guess that line is called inside `commit()` method.

Comment: I think it will works, i'll try later, thanks you!

Comment: @CodeNotFound Check the last edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the primary key `Id` of your navigational property `Endereco` you will see that its value is `Guid.Empty` `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

So updating that entity will generate a SQL query with this `WHERE` clause below:

```
WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Of course a line with that empty guid doesn't exist into your table.

Your original code do a mapping with AutoMapper so make sure that all properties are mapped correctly when calling the line below:

```
var cliente = Mapper.Map<Clientes>(clienteViewModel);
```

**Updates**: Based on your comment you also need to be sure that the navigational property state is changed to `EntityState.Modified` (because changing the root entity's state doesn't impact the navigational properties) like below:

```
_context.Entry(cliente.Endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I made some changes and now the Endereco.Id is not empty, but the error is the same

Comment: That's it!! Now it's working like a charm! Thank you very much!